# Login com AJAX no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou estudando sobre aplicativos mobile, hibridos, estou usando o phonegap e estou tendo um problema. Não consigo fazer login, o ajax manda as variaveis direitinho e o php retorna um valor porem o ajax nao esta capturando esse valor para verificacao se existe ou nao o usuario no banco de dados. Segue o codigo html e php:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Blank App</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    function Login(){
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var senha = document.getElementById('senha').value;
        console.log(email);
        console.log(senha);
        var json = {'email':email, 'senha':senha};

     $.ajax({
            type:"POST", crossDomain: true, cache: false,
            url:"http://localhost/projeto/login.php",
            data:json,
            dataType:'json',
            sucess: function (data){
                console.log("logou");
                if(data=='logou'){
                    console.log("logou");
                    alert("logou");
                    window.location.href="inicial.html";
                }else{
                    alert ( " Obrigado " );
                }
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body class='tela_login'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <form id='formulario' action=login.php method=post></form>
        <img src="/imagem/icone_login.png" class='img_login'">
        <p><input type=text class='form-login' id='email' placeholder='Insira seu email'></p>
        <p><input type=password class='form-login' id='senha' placeholder='Insira sua senha'></p>
        <button type=button class='btn-logar' onclick="Login()">Logar</button>
        <button type=submit class='btn-cadastrar'>Cadastrar</button>
        </div>
        <form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
require "conexao.php";

$email=$_POST['email'];
$senha=$_POST['senha'];

$query=mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM tbl_cliente where email='$email' and senha='$senha'");
$cont=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($cont>0){
     echo "logou";
}else{ 
    echo "falhou";
}
?>
```

Me ajudem, por favor.

Comment: O melhor seria você enviar `http_response_code(code);`
No error qualquer coisa que seja acima de 400, e no sucess outros tipos de _response code_, caso o login não seja encontrado por exemplo, você poderia retornar 404

Comment: e como eu faria isso no codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que seja pelo fato de você indicar na chamada AJAX que o retorno é do tipo JSON, porém no PHP você não retorna um JSON e sim um texto.

Para resolver o problema, insira no ínicio do seu código PHP a seguinte instrução:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

E no retorno de sua instrução, sugiro que faça isso:

```
echo json_encode(['status' => 'logou']);
```

Estamos transformando um array em JSON, com a função nativa `json_encode()`.

No JavaScript, você testará o retorno da seguinte maneira:

```
if (data.status == 'logou') ...
```

Da mesma maneira em casos de falha e etc.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas eu acho que é problema do phonegap mesmo, porque ja tentei de todas as maneiras e nada... Alguem ai já utilizou essa plataforma pra fazer um sistema de login? Não aguento mais quebrar a cabeça por causa de JavaScript

Comment: Beleza! Nunca trabalhei com o PhoneGap, mas já tive esse problema que você relatou com chamadas Ajax sem conseguir recuperar o retorno por conta dos tipos de retorno das requisições. Espero que consiga resolver. Abraços